# UIView animation completion callback?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, iphone-sdk-3.0

Can I setup a function to be called once my animation is complete?  I want to fade a `UIView` and then remove it from the `superView`.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Yes, that's easy:

When you configure your animation

```
[UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
[UIView setAnimationDidStopSelector:@selector(myAnimationStopped:finished:context:)];
```

And define your method like:

```
-(void)myAnimationStopped:(NSString *)animationID 
                 finished:(NSNumber *)finished
                  context:(void *)context {
   // fancy code here
}
```

Doesn't have to be `self` and that method, of course.

Comment: thanks - I was looking through all of the methods, can't believe I missed that one

Comment: haha oldschool ^^ go for the next answer this one is not used anymore

Answer (score 37):

Animation blocks were introduced in iOS4. Apple recommends you use these, and the new methods mostly ask for completion blocks which replace callbacks. For example:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5f
                      delay:0.0f
                    options:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut
                 animations:^{
                   [myView setAlpha:0.0f];
                 }
                 completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                   [myView removeFromSuperview];
                 }];
```